# Is it possible to allow users to connect to their own database from a published web application?

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server

I started working on a .net app that would allow users to make a connection to their own Sql Server database. Is this even possible? None of the db information would be saved, it would just be used to connect and allow them to use their own stored procedures in the application rather than predefined/fake data.

Comment: What do you mean by "their own Sql Server database" ? Are they going to have to setup a local copy of Sql Server? Are you creating a local copy for them?

Comment: Sure this is possible. Sounds totally bizarre but not a huge deal. Capture the credentials from the user and make a connection. It really isn't any different than any other database connection...well except that this is rather strange and raises questions about why this is a good thing to do.

Comment: @RyanWilson As in, I installed Sql Server on my own computer, and I can connect to the server through SSMS. I then go to the application at mywebapp.com, and connect to the same server I use locally.

Comment: The only real challenge here is that the web server must have access to the "remote" server. Meaning if your webserver is in the DMZ you likely can't connect to computer inside the firewall or another computer on another domain etc.

Comment: Your question is not clear enogh, do you men that they can connect to multiple DB, one for the application and another one for testing ? or you mean you want to connect locally ?. If locally then yes it is possible, in the connection string provide the local host connection data then you will have it. @ThomasColbert

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed!

If you know which connection string should be used for each user to connect to the corresponding database, instead of connecting to one database using it's connection string (like we see in every basic example), use the user's connection string and open the connection with it.

As long as you set the SQLConnection with the wanted connection string you can connect each time to another DB, easily.